# multiple validation in vb.net [ non 0 and numeric only]

Tags: vb.net, validation, numbers, numeric

How can I multi validate a text box? I only want the user to input integer but the integer shouldn't be 0 or less, how can I do this? This is what I've done:

```
If Val(txtCopies.Text) <= 0 Then
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Number should be bigger than 0 ")  

    If IsNumeric(txtCopies.Text) = False Then
      ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Number only")
    Else
      blabla
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If IsNumeric(txtCopies.Text) = True AND CINT(txtCopies.Text) >= 0 Then

  'Validation Passed
Else
  ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Number should be bigger than 0 ")  

End If
```

there you go, else please explain better

you can also do

```
If IsNumeric(txtCopies.Text) = True AND CINT(txtCopies.Text) >= 0 Then

  'Validation Passed
Else
     if not(IsNumeric(txtCopies.Text) = True) then
       ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Numbers Only")
     else
       ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Number should be bigger than 0 ")  
    end if  
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim intValue As Integer

If Not Integer.TryParse(TxtBox.Text, intValue) OrElse intValue < 0 Then


Else


End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done VB but here you go:

It has to be able to convert whatever is in the text box to an integer.
to do this, it checks if the string is numeric, if it is, then the num variable takes its value (so it can be checked). If this value is greater than 0 then it says it's not valid.

It needs to be a nested If statement for this to happen.

```
    Sub OnClick()
        Dim str As String
        Dim num As Integer

        str = TextBox1.Text
        If IsNumeric(str) Then
            num = str
            If num <= 0 Then
                TextBox1.Text = "Sorry, not valid"
            End If
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "Sorry, not a number"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style ..

```
If Not IsNumeric(txtCopies.Text) And Val(txtCopies.Text) <= 0 Then
  ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Number only")
Else
  If Val(txtCopies.Text) <= 0 Then
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtCopies, "Number should be bigger than 0 ") 
  Else
    'Blabla 
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If interger. Parse(hours Text box. Tex)<=10 then
' code to perform calculation
Else
Message box.Show("Two many hours."," Invalid Data",MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End if

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).